# Averages of $L(1,\chi)$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, quadratic-reciprocity

Let $(\frac{m}{n})$ denote the usual quadratic Jacobi symbol
and $\mu(n)$ be the Moebius function.
The series
$$
\sum_{\substack{m,n \in \mathbb{N} \\ m,n\equiv 1 \mod{4}}}
\frac{\mu^2(mn)}{(mn)^{1+\epsilon}}
\left(\frac{m}{n}\right)
$$
converges absolutely for all $\epsilon>0$
but
I would like to ask 
whether it converges
for $\epsilon=0$.

Comment: Maybe try asking this on MathOverflow

Comment: thanks, i just did:http://mathoverflow.net/questions/198512/averages-of-l-frac12-chi